# Matlab scatterhist plots - display only one histogram

Tags: matlab, properties, histogram, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

In Matlab, I want to plot data as a scatter plot, and display the marginal histogram at the side of **one axis only**.

I came across the scatterhist() function, which does exactly what I was looking for, except it **always displays** marginal histograms for **both X and Y axes**. Surely there's a way to remove one, but can't find the options.

My code as an example:

```
h = scatterhist(xrange, ydata, ...
    'Kernel','on', 'Location', 'SouthEast', ...
    'Direction','out', 'Marker','.');
```

An image of my problem is below (I am using the kernel density line instead of the actual histogram):

[image]

*Note: I am able to open the property editor for the figure and manually remove a histogram by clicking and deleting, and furthermore access the source code for that modified figure, but this doesn't seem to provide me with a solution.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `scatterhist` creates three axes. Calling it as `h = scatterhist(...)` gives a 1×3 vector `h` with handles to those axes. You only need to delete the second:

```
h = scatterhist(...);
delete(h(2))
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I was playing around with h(2) properties for ages (i.e. "h(2).Visible"... etc.), but simply didn't realise 'delete' was a function/option.

Comment: I will 'accept' this answer as soon as I can. Thanks again for showing me how simple this was!!

Comment: Glad I could help!